# Как фильтровать ListView в Android?

Tags: android, listview

у меня есть заполненный `ListView` и `EditText`. Как сделать так, чтобы, когда я вводил в `edit` текст, у меня в соответствии с введенным текстом обновился список `ListView`?

Comment: Что имелось ввиду под "в соответствии с введенным текстом обновился список"? Нужно обновлять список после каждого введенного символа или при определенном количестве символов, или после произведения чтения из поля "edit"?

Comment: Ваш адаптер должен получать команду к обновлению (перерисовке) списка. Эта команда может запускаться каким то событием.  Например, если данные которыми заполняется список хранятся в массиве, то нужно:  1) считать данные с "edit". 2) передать их в массив. 3) дать команду адаптеру перерисовать список adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Android существует специальный фильтр `ListView` по элементам списка реализуется он так

```
            edit2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            //Когда пользователь вводит какой-нибудь текст:
            Main6Activity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Сдесь `MainActivity` - название активити
`adapter`-адаптер листвью
    `edit2`- едит куда вводится текст для поиска

Comment: Если честно, то вы путаете понятия. Android Studio никакого отношения к listview не имеет. Это всего лишь среда разработки в которой вы пишете код. Код можно писать и в других средах разработки и там этот код так же будет работать.